# Is it enough to use HTMLEncode to display uploaded text?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xss, html-encode

We're allowing users to upload pictures and provide a text description. Users can view this through a pop up box (actually a div ) via javascript. The uploaded text is a parameter to a javascript function. I 'm worried about XSS and also finding issues with HTMLEncode(). 
We're using HTMLEncode to guard against XSS. Unfortunately, we're finding that HTMLEncode() only replaces '<' and '>'. We also need to replace single and double quotes that people may include. Is there a single function that will do all these special type characters or must we do that manually via .NET string.Replace()?

Comment: You could use [AntiXSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814) which uses white-lists with allowed elements. You can [download it here](http://wpl.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately, we're finding that HTMLEncode() only replaces '<' and '>'.

Assuming you are talking about [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx), that *does* encode the double-quote character. It also encodes as character references the range U+0080 to U+00FF, for some reason.

What it doesn't encode is the single quote. Bit of a shame but you can usually work around it by using only double quotes as attribute value delimiters in your HTML/XML. In that case, `HtmlEncode` is enough to prevent HTML-injection.

However, `javascript` is in your tags, and `HtmlEncode` is decidedly not enough to escape content to go in a JavaScript string literal. JavaScript-encoding is a different thing to HTML-encoding, so if that's the reason you're worried about the single quote then you need to employ a JS string encoder instead.

(A JSON encoder is a good start for that, but you would want to ensure it encodes the U+2028 and U+2029 characters which are, annoyingly, valid in JSON but not in JavaScript. Also you might well need some variety of HTML-escaping on top of that, if you have JavaScript in an HTML context. This can get hairy; it's usually better to avoid these problems by hiding the content you want in plain HTML, for example in a hidden input or custom attribute, where you can use standard HTML-escaping, and then read that data from the DOM in JS.)

Answer (score 0):

If the text description is embedded inside a JavaScript string literal, then to prevent XSS, you will need to escape special characters such as quotes, backslashes, and newlines. The `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` method is *not* suitable for this task.

If the JavaScript string literal is in turn embedded inside HTML (for example, in an attribute), then you will need to apply HTML encoding as well, on top of the JavaScript escaping.

You can use Microsoft's [Anti-Cross Site Scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814) library to perform the necessary escaping and encoding, but I recommend that you try to avoid doing this yourself. For example, if you're using WebForms, consider using an `<asp:HiddenField>` control: Set its `Value` property (which will be HTML-encoded automatically) in your server-side code, and access its `value` property from client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

how about you htmlencode all of the input with this extended function:

```
private string HtmlEncode(string text)
        {
            char[] chars = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text).ToCharArray();
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(text.Length + (int)(text.Length * 0.1));

            foreach (char c in chars)
            {
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(c);
                if (value > 127)
                    result.AppendFormat("&#{0};", value);
                else
                    result.Append(c);
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }
```

this function will convert all non-english characters, symbols, quotes, etc to html-entities..
try it out and let me know if this helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC2 or ASP.NET 4 you can replace <%= with <%: to encode your output. It's safe to use for everything it seems (like HTML Helpers).

There is a good write up of this here: [New <%: %> Syntax for HTML Encoding Output in ASP.NET 4 (and ASP.NET MVC 2)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)